# Laravel faker Syntax

Tags: laravel, faker, artisan-migrate

I am following a tutorial and I am trying to get faker to work to put in data in the Database. I am using this code.

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Listing>
 */
class ListingFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'title' => $this->faker->sentence(),
            // 'tags' => 'Laravel, API, Backend',
            // 'company' => $this->faker()->company(),
            // 'location' => $this->faker()->city(),
            // 'email' => $this->faker()->companyemail(),
            // 'website' => $this->faker()->url(),
            // 'description' => $this->faker()->paragraph(5),

        ];
    }
}
```

I am just limiting it to the title to try to figure out what my problem is.
Here is the errors I am getting.

```
` INFO  Seeding database.


   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'tags' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `listings` (`title`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Ea a voluptatem cum quidem eos aperiam., 2023-10-23 15:46:39, 2023-10-23 15:46:39))       

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:801
    797▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    798▕                 );
    799▕             }
    800▕
  ➜ 801▕             throw new QueryException(       
    802▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    803▕             );
    804▕         }
    805▕     }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:580
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'tags' doesn't have a default value")    

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:580
      PDOStatement::execute()`
```

I have tried to copy the code exactly but I can't find my error.
Thanks in advance for your help.

I just wanted to seed the database with some bogus data for testing

Comment: Uncomment your tags line, that value is required since the field doesn't allow null values.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that but It didn't change the results

Comment: It should change the error message. Does it still say `Field 'tags' doesn't have a default value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the `tags` column is nullable, you need to pass it to create the model from a factory.

```php
Listing::factory()->create(['tags' => 'Some, Tags, Here']);
```

Comment: I re-enabled all of the commented lines.
    My Tags line looks like this 
'tags' => 'Laravel, API, Backend',

But I still get the same errors

Comment: So I am going line by line and I now have the Title and the tags coming in, But when I add the Company now it is throwing an error. Since the Tags are just text does it cause an issue because that is not using Faker? 
    'title' => $this->faker->sentence(),
            'tags' => 'Laravel, API, Backend',
            'company' => $this->faker()->company(),

Comment: What's the error for the company?

Comment: @Mr.Formula if you have a follow-up queation, then please accept this answer as a solution and ask a new question. It is unfair to ask multiple follow-up questions as comments.

Comment: BadMethodCallException 

  Call to undefined method Database\Factories\ListingFactory::faker()

I am just playing with changing the order and removing fields to try to figure out where the error is.

Comment: I see that the video I am following is in Laravel 9 and my framework installed is 10.26. maybe this is what is causing my issue.

Comment: Found the issue. It was a version upgrade. You don't have to use $this-> any more. I changed it to the stuff listed below and it worked
 'title' => fake()->sentence(),
            'company' => fake()->company(),
            'tags' => 'Laravel, API, Backend',          
            'location' => fake()->city(),
            'email' => fake()->companyemail(),
            'website' => fake()->url(),
            'description' => fake()->paragraph(5),